# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate with multiple field update operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd to set a min value, max value and increment a count within a document with a single update but can't find the correct syntax

This works for incrementing the counts in the document:

```
Temperature.findOneAndUpdate(dailyQuery,
    { $inc: { temperature_sum : thermometer.temperature, count : 1 }},
    {upsert : true}, function(err, dailyTemp) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.error(dailyTemp);
});
```

I'd like to also set min max values also and thought the update command would be along the lines of

```
Temperature.findOneAndUpdate(dailyQuery,
    { $inc: { temperature_sum : thermometer.temperature, count : 1 },
        $max :{ max_temp : thermometer.temperature},
        $min :{ min_temp : thermometer.temperature}},
    {upsert : true}, function(err, dailyTemp) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.error(dailyTemp);
});
```

But I get

```
MongoError: exception: Invalid modifier specified $min
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code works fine when I try it. The `$min` operator was added in MongoDB 2.6, are you using a version older than that?

Comment: Thank-you, that's what the problem is, I'm using 2.4.10 on the pi. I didn't think to run the command manually in mongo itself, but yes $max and $min are not valid. If you set this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the `$min` (and `$max`) operators were introduced in MongoDB 2.6 and you're using 2.4.10.